# Why should we disable automatic migrations in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have been told that enabling automatic migrations for EntityFramework is a bad idea mainly in production.

1. Do we really have to disable them?
2. Do we have to disabled them for all environments (Develop,release,production)?
3. Can you describe an alternative deployment process to replace automatic
   migrations?

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: "I have been told" - why didn't you ask that person for argumentation?

Comment: I asked him but I am not convinced. So that's why I am asking this question. Could you provide an answer for my question?

Comment: Its a very open ended question, here could be various factor for you it may not be suitable. one of the factor would be deployment do you have continuous deployment for the application ??

Comment: Why is it a very open ended question? I just want to know if it's good or not and why. And if you know any alternative process to it.

Answer (score 3):

Talking from an Oracle SQL perspective, there are certain changes that don't necessarily work out of the box, so when the migration code is created, some manual adjustments need to be made.

Consider the following:

A required column is added to an existing table. In order to retain existing data, I modify the generated migration, to create a nullable column, assign an initial value and then edit the column as not-nullable.

There are many other things where automated migrations might have some (unexpected) side effect and I suspect this is worse with the Oracle data provider but there will be some problematic cases for MS SQL.

In team development, conflicting migrations might be a concern if multiple developers change the database model.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bad or good idea, but more a good practice to do [manual migration](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/entityframework/understanding-entity-framework-code-first-migrations) with Entity Framework.

Why :

- Speed Issue : EF will try to detect if Model is different from Database, and build it if it's true.
- Suppressing Data on DB : you suppress a model or dbset by mistake, it would destroy the table/Data in DataBase. In production environment is not very recommended to use AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed.  In other way, if you set this to false, it would thrown Exception and can cause accessibility problem.
  ([AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.automaticmigrationdatalossallowed(v=vs.113).aspx))

[Another good doc](http://blog.cellenza.com/publications/c-and-ef-tutorial-entity-framework-code-first-migrations/) about entity framework migration

The main use of AutoMigration is for Code First, it's allow to the developper to produce more "code" than build the DataBase. Just create model and run it would build the Db, destroy what you suppress from model or modify column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really helpful. I've got a question though. I was watching a Julie Lerman pluralsight course about EF code first migrations and she suggested to export the migrations to a script for production environment but she doesn't explain why. What do you think about this?

Comment: Don't know this course but i think she prefere to update database by sql scripting and without entity framework migration system.